# How can I Create 3D Billboard Curved Screen Using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, anamorphism

[image]

I want Create Digital Signage like this picture for 3D Billboard Curved Screen using Unity.

I found method for make that.

1. Renders the camera at a three-dimensional angle.
2. Map the rendered image once to a screen object in the camera position.
3. Burn the image mapped to the screen object.

However, I have to use Unity, and I couldn't find a way to run the following process other than Blend.

There are how to make 3d Billboard Curved Screen using Blender.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xK3q641dd2c
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chqwnEIFr9Q

I have to use Unity, so I want to know how to proceed with the above process with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Set everything up in Blender and import it to Unity, make sure the camera position is the same in Blender and Unity and has the same resolution. Create your animation in unity, then install the [com.unity.recorder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.recorder@2.0/manual/index.html) package, and record an Image Sequence of your animation. Afterwards use that image sequence in Blender and follow the tutorial until you get the morphed image sequence.

Now you can either use that image sequence in the real world, or import it to unity to play on the virtual screen.